# How to increase the size of the value in redis?

Tags: redis

In redis, a value can have a max of the length of 512MB. According to this [link](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/757), the length can be increased. But the procedure is not given properly to increase the size. Can anyone give the steps to increase the value size? I am using redis version 5.

Comment: Normally, it's a bad idea to have such a huge value. It's very inefficient to get the whole value from Redis. One of the cases that need huge value might be taking Redis value as a bitmap, since the bit operation is still very fast even if the value is very large. However, do you really need a bitmap with more than `2**29` bits?

Comment: @for_stack Is it possible to increase only for string type?

Comment: As @Mike mentioned in his answer, you have to modify the code, and build it from source. Also as I mentioned above, it's a bad idea to have such a huge string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is to an Issue that discusses the possibility of increasing the string sizes in Redis, when you build it from source.

There is a link to a patch that does just that (https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/4568) in one of the comments. Feel free to apply the patch and build your own Redis version that supports large values.

But there appears to be no way to just “configure” this without building Redis from source. I’m not sure what you need these large values for but beware of building from source and deploying forked/untested code to production - especially if you don’t feel confident in your understanding of the changes, the build process and the process of further keeping up with upstream changes.